# Error when lauching the command "bash"

Tags: solaris

I'm using SUN Solaris-8 and i tried to install an application to run it into : i failed because i got insuffisant disk space. So today i delete some useless thing in the disk but when i try to execute the command bash this message figure out : Segmentation Fault (core dumped).

I read in some forums that's a consequence of a lack of space in the disk or in the memory that's why i got this but i can't fix it .

I also tried the command adb core and i got this :

```
NT_GWINDOWS currently unsupported note segment entry.
core file = core -- program ``bash'' on platform SUNW,Sun-Blade-1500
SIGSEGV: Segmentation Fault
data address not found
```

Any idea about that .?

Comment: `i delete some useless thing in the disk` ... Two questions: 1) What did you erase. Are you sure that it was harmless?  2) Which program did you try to install? Did it update some libraries which bash also uses? Did you try reinstalling it after you created some space. (Optionally from another shell than bash).

Comment: i erase some old database , i want to install a new database that iit will be deploy in an application for a company. The error is showed before i erased anything